# Awk associative array increment

Tags: awk

I have a awk command which I am trying to understand what it does. I have duplicated the file from etc/passwd.

I have did some research that the $4 is the forth column, which is the group. The a[$4] loads all the items from $4 into a associative array. However, I don't understand what does the ++== do.

```
awk -F: 'a[$4]++==2 { print $4 }' passwd
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `++` and `==` are two separate operators. The `++` is the post-increment of `a[$4]++` and the `==` is a comparison. Writing it with spaces makes it more clear: `a[$4]++ == 2`. Btw. the post-fix means that the previous value of `a[$4]` is compared i.e. the old value is returned but incremented afterwards.

Comment: a[$4]++ increments a[$4] by one, == 2 checks whether it's 2 or not. This script basically prints every value that appears in the 4th column more than twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following is the explanation for shown code by OP, only for explanation purposes not for running the code it is.

```
-F:                       ##Setting field separator as colon here.
a[$4]++                   ##Creating array a with index/key 4th field of current line and ++ will do increment to its same occurrence here, to get to know how many times same 4th field has occurred.
==2                       ##Then checking condition if it has count 2 here(occurrence of same 4th field in array a has its count 3(since we are doing post increment)) then do following.
{ print $4 }' passwd      ##Printing 4th field of that line.
```

1 thing here, even your Input_file has more than 3 occurrences of 4th field it is going to print 3rd occurrence only so in case you want to print all those Lines where 4th field comes 2 or more times then change your code to:

```
awk -F: '++a[$4]>=2 { print $4 }' passwd
```

---

---

***Example of array execution:***

Let's say we have following Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
a,b,c,1st,bla bla
a,b,c,2nd,bla bla
a,b,c,1st, bla bla
```

Now creating array with `a[$4]++` will save values inside array like this:

`a[1st]=2`, `a[2nd]=1` and so on for OP's understanding I am showing it like this fashion.

We could get and understand this with a for loop which traverse inside array like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {a[$4]++} END{for(key in a){print "Index of array is:" key " And value is:" a[key]}}'  Input_file
Index of array is:2nd And value is:1
Index of array is:1st And value is:2
```